# How to get & use Widget Element's Action in fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

In need of a good Ui design for my app with tab layout, i searched in google and i found one UI which is using View Pager and Action bar Tabs.

Link is: 
    http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

i downloaded the template & imported to eclipse.i to tried use that template, don't know where to add my activity coding. 
i uploaded one of the fragment below, and i tried to get action of a button. but "it shows create a method finViewById".

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
        Button bu=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        return rootView;
    }
```

i don't know much about fragment. I searched in google but i am not able get solution related to this. anyone pls can help me how and where to add my activity coding using above UI Template. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not related to your code. So edit it.

Comment: edit your question. Activity cannot be added in a Fragment.

Comment: why dis like for my question can i know that?

Comment: i changed my topic remove your dislike..

Comment: Thank u for removing dislike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);
    Button bu=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
Button bu=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```